# Issue with a @ManyToMany relationship persisting into reference tables

Tags: json, hibernate, jpa, spring-roo, spring-data-jpa

I have a **Curriculum entity** which is as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Curriculum {

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Language> languages;
    ...
```

I am trying to persist a Curriculum instance but **the constraint is that the Language instances are already in database**.

How can I make sure that when a call to persist is made, a line is inserted into the `curriculum` table, the `curriculum_languages` mapping table **but not into** the `language` table as it is a reference table which is already populated?

**edit 1**:

-Here is the error I get if I don't specify the `Cascade.ALL` attribute:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.bignibou.domain.Language
```

-If I do specify the `Cascade.ALL`, new lines with new IDs are insterted into the `language` table which is obviously not what I want...

**edit 2**: Note that I use Spring Data JPA in order to persist my instances and the data coming from the browser is a JSON object as follows:

```
{"curriculum":{"languages":[{"id":46,"description":"Français"},{"id":30,"description":"Chinois"}],"firstName":"Julianito","dateOfBirth":"1975-01-06","telephoneNumber":"0608965874","workExperienceInYears":3,"maxNumberChildren":1,"drivingLicense":true}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to mention that I use optimistic locking. Including the version field in JSon sorted the issue:

```
"languages":[{"id":46,"description":"Français","version":0}],...
```

It would be great if anyone would kindly provide an explanation to this though...

**edit**: version field:

```
@Version
@Column(name = "version")
private Integer Curriculum.version;
```

Comment: Very interesting. This is somehow another question, because I really wondered why you get that Exception, and I don't :)

Comment: Can you show how your @Version field looks like? What type is it (`int` or `Integer`)?

Comment: As far as I know, the @Version field may not be null (if the entity was already persisted, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183013/null-version-fields-in-jpa). And now just a presumption: because it is set to null when decoding the JSON String without that field, hibernate considers the only case when it can be null is when it is in the managed state (but I can't figure why).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most simplest way to achieve it is to load the needed languages from the DB and assign them to the curriculum just before the persist operation.

The logic behind this is the following:

- When a language object comes into your application and is deserialized from JSON, it has an ID field already assigned to it.
- When you try to persist the curriculum (with languages deserialized from JSON) JPA gets confused about those IDs, cause on the one hand it 'should' know about these objects (IDs are set), but on the other hand active JPA session does not know anything about them (they came from outer world of JSON)
- So fetching languages by ID tells JPA who's who.

Comment: Thanks. You mean using the IDs? Also: why do I have this issue with JSon and not with plain html forms?

Comment: yes, just fetch the languages by id from the DB. I will update the answer

Comment: I see what you mean. Ummm... I am sure there might be another way of achieving the desired result without resorting to this workaround...

Comment: depending on your JPA provider you might have a method saveOrUpdate(), it will respect the IDs of the language objects.

Comment: I use Hibernate + Spring Data Jpa. One more thing: does saveOrUpdate really apply to my case: I just want to add lines to a mapping table i.e. `curriculum_languages` (see @ManyToMany)?

Comment: and yeah, this is not as bad, as it may look. Anything that comes from the client should be validated on the server side. Fetching the languages by ID validates the languages that they exist in the database. Furthermore, you might want to refactor the code to hide the IDs, but load languages by name. That will make the client even simplier

Comment: it's difficult to say if saveOrUpdate() works for you in this particular case. I would definitely give it a try

Comment: Funtik: actually I use Spring Data JPA and apparently saveOrUpdate is already used by the Spring Data's save method...

Answer (score 0):

What should happen, when an inexistent `Language` comes with a `Curriculum` instance? Should the `Language` instance simply be ignored or should an `Exception` be thrown?

If an exception should be thrown, just wrap the code that persists the entity in a try-catch block and throw your own Exception. If the language should simply be ignored, just remove it from the `List<Language>` before persisting, e.g if `Language`'s ID is null.

Comment: Hi Andrei, thanks for your reply. My concern is about having to fetch the languages instances from db in order to persist lines into the curriculum_languages mapping table. This looks to me like a workaround/hack...

Comment: Why would you want to fetch them from DB? Hibernate will take care of inserting the rows in the `curriculum_languages` mapping table without that. If the user will pass some inexistent Language IDs, that the database should make the checks and should throw a `ForeignKeyConstraintException`, but everything happens in background.

Comment: I see. The trouble is that with my current setup, what you advise does not work (unless I am missing something...). Have a look a my **edit 1**

Comment: Do you mean that you get an `org.hibernate.TransientObjectException` ALTOUGH all `Language` IDS are already in DB?